# Making a Paid version of a Free app

Tags: ios, xcode

I have made a free version of an app (not in the app store yet) with ad banners and some features.

But I want to make a paid version of this app as well with no ads and more features.

Do I duplicate the app and make 2 separate copies of the app (free and paid) and submit them separately to the app store or is there a way of coding the paid version in to the current free version

I think it may have something to do with targets but i'm not sure

help would be appreciated

Comment: Why not just have one app with in-app purchases allowing the user to hide ads or gain functionality?

Comment: Awhile ago, many apps had a 'lite' version and a paid version.  The recent trend however is freemium, i.e. offer the app download for free, and offer certain upgrades and features via in-app-purchase.  This can include 99 cent upgrade to remove ads etc.

Comment: I'm relatively new to app development and can't seem to get in-purchasing to work at all. So I was going to release both the free and paid apps and then add IAP later.

Comment: Do not offer two apps now and then try to switch to IAP later. It's a giant pain. Get it right the first time or you will regret your decision (and so will your customers).

Comment: Adding in-app purchase to your existing free app is easy.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a single app if you ask me, however, if you do so, you will need to differentiate paid users from free users. You most probably have a database or will have a database where you store which user have paid for the app. If so, then you can authenticate your users and display the free version for users who have not paid for the app, while you can display the paid version for users who have paid.

Comment: What? No. Just use in app purchasing.